# Playing sound in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

How to play sound from audio onClick on parent element in React. I'm not sure what is the right way. Someone suggested me using refs but in what manner? Where to put them? On div that encompass audio tag or audio tag itself? But when i click, i click on div, not on audio tag. So how to play sound from audio when you click on it's parent?
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './style.css';

class DrumMachine  extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pressedKey: null,
            display: null,
            sliderVal: 50,
            volume: 0.5,
            mySwitch: true,
            mySwitchBox: true,
            prevVolume:  0.5,
            fancy: false,
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);
        this.handleVolume = this.handleVolume.bind(this);
        this.onOff = this.onOff.bind(this);
        this.fancyToggle = this.fancyToggle.bind(this);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.mySwitchOn = React.createRef();
        this.mySwitchOff = React.createRef();

        //Refs of audio elements.
        this.Q = React.createRef();
        this.W = React.createRef();
        this.E = React.createRef();
        this.A = React.createRef();
        this.S = React.createRef();
        this.D = React.createRef();
        this.Z = React.createRef();
        this.X = React.createRef();
        this.C = React.createRef();

        //Refs of divs who are parents of audio.
        this.H1 = React.createRef();
        this.H2 = React.createRef();
        this.H3 = React.createRef();
        this.H41 = React.createRef();
        this.H6 = React.createRef();
        this.Dsc_Oh = React.createRef();
        this.Kick_n_Hat = React.createRef();
        this.RP4_KICK_1 = React.createRef();
        this.Cev_H2 = React.createRef();

        this.myRange = React.createRef();

        this.sounds = {
            sound1: null,
            sound2: null,
            sound3: null,
            sound4: null,
            sound5: null,
            sound6: null,
            sound7: null,
            sound8: null,
            sound9: null
        };

        this.parents = {
            parent1: null,
            parent2: null,
            parent3: null,
            parent4: null,
            parent5: null,
            parent6: null,
            parent7: null,
            parent8: null,
            parent9: null
        };

        this.tracks = {
            track1: ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"],
            track2: ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_2.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_3.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Give_us_a_light.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dry_Ohh.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Bld_H1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/punchy_kick_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/side_stick_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Brk_Snr.mp3"],
        };

        this.Id = {
            id1: ["Heater-1", "Heater-2", "Heater-3", "Heater-4", "Clap", "Open-HH", "Kick n' Hat", "Kick", "Closed-HH"],
            id2: ["Chord-1", "Chord-2", "Chord-3", "Shaker", "Open-HH", "Closed-HH", "Punchy-Kick", "Side-Stick", "Snare"],
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyPress);

        this.sounds = {
            sound1: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Q.current),
            sound2: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.W.current),
            sound3: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.E.current),
            sound4: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.A.current),
            sound5: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.S.current),
            sound6: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.D.current),
            sound7: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Z.current),
            sound8: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.X.current),
            sound9: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.C.current)
        };

        this.parents = {
            parent1: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H1.current),
            parent2: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H2.current),
            parent3: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H3.current),
            parent4: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H41.current),
            parent5: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H6.current),
            parent6: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Dsc_Oh.current),
            parent7: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Kick_n_Hat.current),
            parent8: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.RP4_KICK_1.current),
            parent9: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Cev_H2.current)
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyPress);

        this.sounds = {
            sound1: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Q.current),
            sound2: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.W.current),
            sound3: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.E.current),
            sound4: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.A.current),
            sound5: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.S.current),
            sound6: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.D.current),
            sound7: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Z.current),
            sound8: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.X.current),
            sound9: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.C.current)
        };

        this.parents = {
            parent1: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H1.current).id,
            parent2: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H2.current).id,
            parent3: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H3.current).id,
            parent4: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H41.current).id,
            parent5: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.H6.current).id,
            parent6: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Dsc_Oh.current).id,
            parent7: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Kick_n_Hat.current).id,
            parent8: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.RP4_KICK_1.current).id,
            parent9: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Cev_H2.current).id
        };
    }

    keyPress(event){

        let myKey = event.key;
        let displayId;

        switch (myKey.toUpperCase()) {
            case this.Q.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound1.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound1.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent1.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.W.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound2.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound2.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent2.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.E.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound3.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound3.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent3.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.A.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound4.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound4.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent4.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.S.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound5.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound5.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent5.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.D.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound6.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound6.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent6.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.Z.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound7.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound7.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent7.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.X.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound8.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound8.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent8.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.C.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound9.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound9.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent9.id;
                }

                break;
            default:

        }

        this.setState({
            display: displayId,
        });

    }

    handleClick(e){

        let displayId;

        switch (e.target.id) {
            case this.H1.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound1.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound1.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent1.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.H2.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound2.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound2.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent2.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.H3.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound3.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound3.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent3.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.H41.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound4.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound4.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent4.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.H6.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound5.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound5.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent5.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.Dsc_Oh.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound6.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound6.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent6.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.Kick_n_Hat.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound7.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound7.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent7.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.RP4_KICK_1.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound8.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound8.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent8.id;
                }

                break;
            case this.Cev_H2.current.id:
                this.sounds.sound9.volume = this.state.volume;
                this.sounds.sound9.play();

                if(this.state.volume===0){
                    displayId = null;
                }
                else{
                    displayId = this.parents.parent9.id;
                }

                break;
            default:

        }

        this.setState({
            display: displayId,
        });

    }

    handleVolume(e){

        this.setState({
            volume: e.target.value/100,
            sliderVal: e.target.value,
            prevVolume: e.target.value/100,
        });

    }

    onOff(e){

        if(this.state.mySwitch){
            this.setState({
                mySwitch: !this.state.mySwitch,
                mySwitchBox: !this.state.mySwitchBox,
                volume: 0,
            });
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                mySwitch: !this.state.mySwitch,
                mySwitchBox: !this.state.mySwitchBox,
                volume: this.state.prevVolume,
            });
        }

    }


    fancyToggle(e){
        this.setState({
            fancy: e.target.checked
        });

    }

    render(){

        const displayId = this.state.display ? this.state.display : "No sound";
        const mySwitch = this.state.mySwitch ? "switchOn" : "switchOff";
        const mySwitchBox = this.state.mySwitchBox ? "switchBoxOn" : "switchBoxOff";
        const switchText = this.state.mySwitch ? "On" : "Off";
        const fancyId = this.state.fancy ? this.Id.id2.map(item2 => item2.replace("-"," ")) : this.Id.id1.map(item1 => item1.replace("-"," "));
        const track = this.state.fancy ? this.tracks.track2 : this.tracks.track1;

        console.log("***");
        console.log(fancyId);
        console.log(track);
        console.log("***");

        return(

            <div id="drum-machine" className="grid-container cent" ref={this.myRef}>
                <div id="display" className="item1">{displayId}</div>

                <div id={fancyId[0]} ref={this.H1} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Q<audio id="Q" ref={this.Q} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[0]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[1]} ref={this.H2} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    W<audio id="W" ref={this.W} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[1]}></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[2]} ref={this.H3} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    E<audio id="E" ref={this.E} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[2]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[3]} ref={this.H41} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    A<audio id="A" ref={this.A} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[3]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[4]} ref={this.H6} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    S<audio id="S" ref={this.S} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[4]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[5]} ref={this.Dsc_Oh} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    D<audio id="D" ref={this.D} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[5]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[6]} ref={this.Kick_n_Hat} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Z<audio id="Z" ref={this.Z} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[6]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[7]} ref={this.RP4_KICK_1} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    X<audio id="X" ref={this.X} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[7]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div id={fancyId[8]} ref={this.Cev_H2} className="drum-pad btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    C<audio id="C" ref={this.C} className="clip">
                        <source src={track[8]} type="audio/mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                </div>

                <div className="item3">
                    <input id="switch" type="checkbox" onChange={this.fancyToggle}/>
                    <div className="wrap">
                    <label htmlFor="switch"><span className="rib"></span><span className="rib"></span><span className="rib"></span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="item2">
                    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value={this.state.sliderVal} className="slider" id="myRange" ref={this.myRange} onChange={this.handleVolume}/>
                    <div className="vol">Volume {this.state.sliderVal}</div>
                </div>

                <div id="sw"  className={mySwitchBox} onClick={this.onOff}>
                    <div className={mySwitch} ref={this.mySwitchOn}>{switchText}</div>
                </div>

            </div>

        );

    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<DrumMachine/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Ignore commented out code, it was said to me that is not a god way to do like this. Also, said code is what i already tried. Here is working [example code.](https://codepen.io/codename11/pen/qJEbLw)

Updated code. Now only things left to resolve is that bottom left button which is charged to alternate between two sound track collections. In fact, it does what is supposed to, but sounds stay the same. Upon inspecting audio's source subtag i found no errors and nothing. It has proper file to play ... It boggles my mind what is the problem here, since everything is up to spec ... What should that button do: Upon clicking on it, it should change all divs ids that encompass audio elements, change to values stated in fancyId variable in render(), also what it should is to also change to different audio track stated in variable track in render(). By using console.log() in numerous places i couldn't pinpoint where is the problem. I inspected audio elements after clicking on button and source for audio is changed how it's supposed to. I'm hopping' new set of eyes can shed a light on this precarious situation in whom i'm currently reside.

Edit2: I think i found solution. Instead of checking if the checkbox e.g. "the button" is pressed(checked) in render(), i checked for this state(fancy) in methods for playing sounds i.e. handleClick() and keyPress(). So, ... if it's false use one sets of sound, if it's true use other sets of sounds. Check codepen, it's updated.

Comment: Too much code sample. Please add relevant code samples only

Comment: @underscore Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I would use one player rather than many and put all those audio url in an array and loop them threw in the render method as a list of text links. When the user clicks on a link i would load that player via the state with a current audio file. Something like this:

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = {
    currentAudioFile: 0,
  }
  this.audiofiles = [
    {
      label: 'Heater-1',
      url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'
    },
    {
      label: 'Heater-2',
      url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And then in the render method:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <audio id="Player" controls>
        <source src={this.audiofiles[this.state.currentAudioFile].url} type="audio/mp3"></source>
      </audio>
      <ul>
        {
          this.audiofiles.map((item,i) => (
            <li>
              <span
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    currentAudioFile: i,
                  })
                }}
              >
                {item.label}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I hope that could be to any help for you.

Comment: I was planning to do something like this, but want to make it functional first. Anyroad, keypress function is up and running, using refs of audio tag and not document.getElementBy's. Need to make something for handleClick also. Check my pen in my post for it.

Comment: Codepen example is updated. Now both, handleClick and keyPress are rewritten to utilize refs.